# Handling Authorization Data for Google APIs Under Review

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am operating a service using the Google Calendar API. For a new feature, there is a need to add scopes. While undergoing the review or even if the review is unsuccessful, can the authorization of already approved users be utilized effectively during the review process?

The handling of data under review, so it is unclear what will happen.